# SQL SUM() function ignoring WHERE clause and CASE statement

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

```
    SELECT      u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as 'User',
            COUNT(*) as 'Number of Calls',
            CONVERT(varchar(4), SUM(CASE WHEN c.FromTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
                THEN DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime) ELSE 0 END) / 60) + ':' + 
            CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.FromTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
                THEN DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime) ELSE 0 END) % 60 < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END +
            CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime)) % 60) as 'Total Time Spent',
            CONVERT(varchar(4), AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime)) / 60) + ':' +
            CASE WHEN AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime)) % 60 < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END +
            CONVERT(varchar(2), AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, c.FromTime, c.ToTime)) % 60) as 'Average Call Time'
FROM        Calls c
JOIN        Users u ON u.UserID = c.TakenBy
WHERE       c.FromTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY    u.UserID, u.FirstName, u.LastName
ORDER BY    u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName
```

The preceding SQL query returns the correct "Number of Calls" but the "Total Time" and "Average Time" are always the same regardless of the # of calls (which is obviously wrong).

I've read and tried to implement using the CASE WHEN __ Then value ELSE 0 inside SUM but it still returns an incorrect value.

The only way I can get this query to return correct results is if I completely strip out all other info, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, FromTime, ToTime)) FROM Calls WHERE c.FromTime BETWEEN...
```

How can I still use my JOIN and GROUP BY and get the aggregate functions to give me the results I want?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I think you are trying to do too many things in the select columns,
can you try to break this a little bit into sub queries?

Comment: To clarify this build a select with your target values first. there to check the correct results. afterwards you group them and sum/avg the columns.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters that you need to simplify your sample code to try and find the problem. So if you could repost your sample SQL without the extra CASE statements (which shouldn't be necessary anyway).

Comment: If you do a plain `select *` (and comment the `group by`), do the *same* rows from `c` appear as multiple rows in the result set? - is it the duplication of those rows that are affecting the totals, and that you're seeking to eliminate?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I figured out it was a data problem with one of the rows; this query works as intended as is. (I was able to take the CASE out of the SUM function because the WHERE worked after all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off with a subquery, e.g. in the SELECT part, add something like `(SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... WHERE ...) AS total_sum`.